# How to delete any cookie where the cookie name start with "test"

Tags: jquery, jquery-cookie

I generate cookie with a name that start with "test" followed by a number using [jQuery-Cookie Plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

How can I remove all cookies that start with "test"

normally "if I know the exact cookie name I would do this

```
$.removeCookie('test10575');
```

but in this call all I know that the cookie starts with the "test"

How to delete any cookie where the cookie name start with "test"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$.each($.cookie(), function (name, value) {
  if (/^test/.test(name)) {
    $.removeCookie(name);
  }
});
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/puwuxe/1/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a wildcard option but you can get a list of all cookies with `$.cookie();` and use it to find all starting with 'test' in order to delete them:

```
for (cookie in $.cookie()) {   
    if (cookie.substring(0, 4) == "test") {
        $.removeCookie(cookie);
    }
}
```